# cx_Freeze building error

Tags: python, gcc, cx-freeze

Im trying to install cx_Freeze for Python 3.3. However, when compiling the source I get this error

```
gcc -pthread build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/source/bases/Console.o -L/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m -lpython3.3 -o build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/cx_Freeze/bases/Console -Xlinker -export-dynamic -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Since I'm a newbie I couldn't really figure out what's missing so I've tried installing **libpython3.3-dev** and **python3.3-dev**, but this doesn't solve the problem. I don't know if this is wheather a Python or gcc problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you show us the file you are using to compile your source?

Comment: Is there actually a `libpython3.3.a` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m`?

Comment: Is this on Ubuntu/Debian? They do something odd with Python shared libraries that breaks cx_Freeze. [This bug report](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304) has a workaround.

Comment: @anongeneric I'm just using the command `python3.3 setup.py build` (as README states) on setup.py found in source package [cx-freeze.sourceforge.net](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @MarkkuK. actually there's a file named `libpython3.3m.a`

Comment: @ThomasK The distribution is Kali Linux which is a branch of Debian

Comment: @ThomasK The workaround didn't work for me

Comment: @ngwdaniel hello bro, Correct this problem? I also have this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create link and it will be ok!

```
sudo ln /usr/local/lib/libpython3.3m.a /usr/local/lib/libpython3.3.a
```